# Pourquoi pas d'accent grave à cela ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques

En français, l'accent grave, quand il n'est pas sur la lettre `e`, sert à distinguer des homophones courants :

- *à* (préposition) / *a* (verbe *avoir*)
- *çà* (adverbe) / *ça* (pronom démonstratif)
- *là* (adverbe) / *la* (article, pronom ou nom)
- *(re)voilà* (mot figé) / voila (verbe *voiler*)
- *où* (adverbe ou pronom invariable) / *ou* (conjonction de coordination)

On le rencontre également dans les adverbes *deçà*, *delà* et *déjà*. Je pense que ceux-ci complètent la liste des accents graves sur une lettre autre que `e` (sauf imports, de l'italien par exemple).

Pourquoi ne met-on pas d'accent au pronom démonstratif *celà* pour le distinguer de la conjugaison du verbe *[celer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/celer)* ?

(Je pense connaître la réponse, mais je cherche une référence, pas juste une conjecture. Il me semble que l'utilisation de l'accent grave a été codifiée par l'Académie au moment de la normalisation de l'orthographe au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, et obéit à une règle précise : laquelle ?)

Comment: Juste afin de compléter ta liste : *deçà* (notamment dans *en deçà de ...* en opposition à *au-delà de ...*)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Tiens oui, j'ai dû le zapper quand j'ai séparé les paires des singletons. Merci.

Comment: Même avec imports je n'ai trouvé dans le [lefff](http://www.labri.fr/perso/clement/lefff/) que *omertà* et *pietà*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je crois qu'il y a là un flottement assez prolongé sur l'emploi ou non de l'accent grave sur *cela/celà*.

Pour donner quelques exemples, J.B. Roche dans ses *Entretiens sur l'orthographe françoise, et autres objets analogues*, Nantes, 1777, écrit régulièrement `celà` ([en ligne](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5PIFAAAAQAAJ)), tout comme E. Jacquemard dans ses *Éléments de grammaire française à l'usage des enfants*, Paris, 1805 ([en ligne](http://books.google.fr/books?id=i8NFAAAAcAAJ)), et sans doute bien d'autres encore.

D'après le Dictionnaire de Littré :

> Des grammairiens ont demandé que l'Académie mît un accent grave, *celà*, puisqu'elle en met un sur *là* et sur *voilà* ; ç'aurait l'avantage d'effacer une inconséquence d'orthographe. Mais, l'accent grave sur *là* n'ayant d'autre objet que de le distinguer, pour l'œil, de *la* article, du moment que dans un mot, comme *cela*, il n'y a plus de confusion possible, il est inutile de surcharger l'écriture ; c'est ainsi que *dû* se distingue de *du*, au lieu qu'au pluriel on écrit *dus* sans accent parce qu'il n'y a plus rien à distinguer.

Comme on peut le remarquer, cette explication n'est pas entièrement conséquente, car il n'y a pas plus ou moins de raisons d'écrire *voilà* que **celà* (et que dire de *déjà* dont on voit mal quelle confusion il peut engendrer).

Les différents dictionnaires de l'Académie, dans leur article «accent», ne sont pas plus explicites, et disent à peu près tous la même chose, à quelques nuances près, depuis la 1<sup>re</sup> édition (1694) :

> On met un accent grave, sur *là*, adverbe de lieu ; pour le distinguer de *la*, pronom féminin.

À partir de la seconde, le pronom devient article (2<sup>e</sup> édition, 1718):

> On met un accent grave sur, *là*, adverbe de lieu, pour le distinguer de, *la*, article feminin.

À partir de la 3<sup>e</sup> édition, on ne précise plus qu'il s'agit d'un adverbe de lieu, mais toujours pas de modifications essentielles (1740) :

> On met un accent grave sur *là*, adverbe, pour le distinguer de *la*, article.

À peu près la même chose dans les 4<sup>e</sup> et 5<sup>e</sup> éditions (1762, 1798) :

> On le met aussi sur *là*, adverbe, pour le distinguer de *la*, article

Et enfin, à partir de la 6<sup>e</sup>, on rajoute la distinction concernant le verbe avoir (1835, 1879, 1932-1935) :

> on le met aussi sur *à*, préposition, pour le distinguer de *a*, troisième personne du singulier du présent de l'indicatif du verbe Avoir; on le met également sur *là*, adverbe, pour le distinguer de *la*, article, (...)

Je tendrais donc à penser qu'il ne faut pas nécessairement chercher l'existence d'une règle stricte mais qu'il y a sans doute là encore une de ces nombreuses incohérences de l'orthographe française. Il faudrait sans doute vérifier dans l'*Histoire de l'orthographe française* de Nina Catach la présence d'une entrée sur ce point, mais je ne l'ai pas sous la main.

Answer (score 3):

Ma conjecture — mais ce n'est qu'une conjecture, je n'ai aucune référence à apporter — est que l'accent grave comme marqueur pour distinguer des homophones est réservé à des mots invariables : préposition, adverbes. Le pronom démonstratif *cela* est un pronom, variable (c'est une forme singulière neutre, comme *ça*), il ne porte donc pas d'accent grave.

*Cela* suit donc son synonyme *ça* en ne portant pas d'accent grave.