# Why "déjà" with grave accent on "à", not just "déja"?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, diacritiques

I heard that the letter **à** is used instead of **a** to avoid ambiguities like

- **a** (a form of *avoir*) and **à** (a preposition),
- **la** (an article) and **là** (*there*),
- **ça** (*this*) and **çà** (from *çà et là* -- *here and there*),

in several derivatives (in *Oxford Hachette Concise Dictionary*, there are **delà**, **holà**, **voilà**, **deçà**) and in the word **déjà**. Why is it used in this word?

Comment: According to Wiktionnaire, it's because it's the contraction of "dès" and "jà". So just to keep the "reference", as in "corps" with an "s" because of "corpus" in Latin.

Comment: @Larme this could be an answer :)

Comment: La réponse détaillée est dans le dernier § (Prononc. et Orth. ) de http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0

Comment: À l'_Ac._ c'est en [1762](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ja) qu'on ajoute l'accent grave à l'adverbe _jà_ tout court qu'on avait auparavant sans. En ancien fr. on avait des [variantes](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/145889) de _déjà_ sans accent. En quoi l'agglutination expliquerait ici l'accent grave du jà ? Dans _jamais_, et _jadis_, on a la même éty., pourquoi n'a-t-on pas l'accent. Qqn peut expliquer s'il y a _proclise_ et comment ; il n'y a pas d'homographe à distinguer ici ; comment s'appliquerait le rôle séparatif dont on traite au comm. précé., le cas échéant.+1

Comment: Somewhat related: [why no accent on *cela*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/pourquoi-pas-daccent-grave-%C3%A0-cela)

Comment: Confusion is understandable, because in all cases I can find a final *à* will point to something, in space or time. You can even extend to a final grave accent! *Où*, *déjà*, *çà et là*, *deçà*, *(au-)delà*, *voilà*, even *holà* . . . In my dict file I only have *pietà* and *koinè* that don't fit this "rule". Given the historical information from Gilles it seems very clear that this was *not* by design, but I find it a useful mnemonic. Just remember that *cela* doesn't have one, but of course *celui-là* and *cette chose-là* do.

Answer (score 5):

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0) commente ainsi :

> Étymol. et Hist. Ca 1275 des ja « dès à présent » (J. de Meun, Rose, éd. F. Lecoy, 19189); 1465 desja « dès ce moment là (du passé) »
>
> Composé de dès* et de l'a. fr. ja désignant un moment du présent (Passion, éd. d'Arco Avalle, 429, 430) ou du passé (ibid., 131), du lat. class. jam
>
> Dans ces mots, dans lesquels l'a lat. s'est conservé parce qu'ils sont des proclitiques, l'accent grave a donc un rôle distinctif par rapport à un homogr. ou un rôle séparatif par rapport à un mot suiv. de la phrase (cf. Beaul. t. 2, 1927, p. 93, 95).

This accent can therefore be viewed as :

- an addition to the old desja to match the là from "dès ce moment là"
- being there as "proclitique" with the aim of separate the word from the rest of the sentence.

Without further indication, I cannot assess which one it s, but I'd be more in favour of the latter.

Edits: [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0) has example of the accent being there before the contraction :

> HISTORIQUE
>
> XIIIe s.
> "Fame sui, si ne me tairé, Ains voil dès jà tout reveler ; Car fame ne puet riens celer", [la Rose, 19419]

There is also a definition for jà alone [littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/j%C3%A0) / [cntrl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/j%C3%A0):
jà is defined as an adverb, like là. The accent has been used since 1762.

Le [glossaire de la langue romaine](https://books.google.fr/books?id=etVLAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=etymologie+ja&source=bl&ots=fyTQWUnBR8&sig=29bwjR_DWFKwWuQkbbAXQKZxUAo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjpMOViO3LAhVBlxoKHQLkA1oQ6AEIMjAF#v=onepage&q=etymologie%20ja&f=false) also indicate an alternative spelling as `jaz` that can justify the addition of à when it was removed as they did with other `s` in other word.

This other [source](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/a-grave.html) indicates that the academy chose in 1740 to align the usage of the words beginning with `de-` on existing ones like `deçà`.

Comment: Merci ! Pouvez-vous svp. brièvement expliquer en quoi consisterait l'idée de séparation de l'adverbe du reste de la phrase que vous préférez ; en quoi l'accent accomplit-il ça et lequel des deux accents ?

Answer (score 2):

In the past it was written 
Desja.  But loosing the s, the word got a é instead because of the longest pronunciation of the 'e' to emphasis the importance of the word. 
But why a 'à' then ? It's like the location or time prepositions, exactly like 'des' (some) and 'dès' ( from - this moment -) for instance.  (la & là,... )

Comment: The adverb *là* is spelled with an accent to distinguish it from the article *la*. Why would *jà* be spelled with an accent? There's nothing to distinguish it from.

Comment: It's like `hôtel` which was before `hostel`...