# Cela, celà, ceux là

Tags: pronoms, orthographe, démonstratifs, diacritiques

J'ai une recherche à faire à propos des homophones: *cela*, *celà*, *ceux là*... Je ne sais toujours pas discerner entre "cela" et "celà". Pourriez-vous m'aider?

Answer (score 3):

En dehors de l'accent grave et de son extrême rareté, rien ne distingue ***celà*** de ***cela***.

Certains auteurs mettent un accent par analogie avec voici/voilà (ceci/celà) mais l'Académie l'a toujours considéré comme incorrect.

Voir [wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cel%C3%A0) et [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6330/pourquoi-pas-daccent-grave-%C3%A0-cela).